# PHP variable with strpos based on dynamic hash url

Tags: php, variables, strpos

I am dynamically adding a hash to a url - taking that strpos and trying to display a certain footer based on that variable, I know I could just translate the whole page but I need to do this for a client, why isn't it working I suppose is the question?

The url looks like http://www.example.com/#/sp/

Here is my header:

```
<?php 
    $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $isSpanish = strpos($page, '/sp/'); 
    $isSpanishDynamic = strpos('#/sp/', $page);
```

Here is my footer:

```
   <?php if($isSpanishDynamic !== FALSE || $isSpanish !== FALSE) { ?>
                    <li><a href="/">PÁGINA DE INICIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/sp/our-story">HISTORIA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/sp/menu">MENÚ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/sp/contact">CONTACTO US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/sp/order-online">ORDENE POR INTERNET</a></li>
    <?php } else { ?>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/en/our-story">Our Story</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/en/our-menu">Our Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/en/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/en/order">Order Online</a></li>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a url like `http://example.com/#/sp/`, the hash `#/sp/` will never be sent to the server, so you cannot do anything with in PHP unless you interact with the server somehow.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier):

> The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the URI: namely, its processing is **exclusively client-side with no participation from the server**. When an agent (such as a Web browser) requests a resource from a Web server, the agent sends the URI to the server, but does not send the fragment. Instead, the agent waits for the server to send the resource, and then the agent processes the resource according to the fragment value. In the most common case, the agent scrolls a Web page down to the anchor element which has an attribute string equal to the fragment value. Other client behaviors are possible

Comment: I figured that was it but it seemed to work for my dynamic <html> class : <?php echo $page; if($page !== 'intro') { if( $isSpanish !== FALSE ) { echo ' sp';} else { echo ' en';}} ?>

Comment: You might load both, then show the different menus using JavaScript? You might also be interested in the discussion at: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization

Answer (score 1):

As artlung points out, the hash is never sent to the server. There are a few other ways to do it, a query string is probably the next easiest for you to implement. Instead of `/#/sp/`, you could add a query parameter of `/?lang=sp` (full url: http://example.com/?lang=sp).

Then in your PHP script, you could check it using the following code:

```
if ( isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == 'sp' )
```